# Text with color:#0000 is not shown

Tags: html, css, firefox

We had few CSS styles which we used with `<p>` tag. This used to work fine prior to Firefox update to latest 49.0.1. Currently, it doesn't show the text at all. If I remove the class from `<p>` tag, it shows the text.

These are my classes and tags

```css
.primaryText {
  color: #0000;
}
```

```html
<p class="primaryText">Hello world</p>
```

Did anything change with the new Firefox?

Comment: Your CSS is invalid. Try running your code through http://www.css-validator.org/ when you find yourself having single-property and single-browser issues like this.

Answer (score 3):

You are using hex RGBA values. The last digit represents the alpha or the transparency.

The four digit hex is a partial implementation of the hexadecimal #RGBA which is supported on FF (v49).

> "#", followed by four hexadecimal characters (0-9, A-F), where the first digit represents the red part, the second the green part, the third one the blue part and the last one the transparency.

<sup>(source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba))</sup>

You should stick to the normal hex (`#RGB` and `#RRGGBB`) formats until support is wider.

`#000000` && `#000` = Black

`#00000000` &&
`#0000`     = Black that is 100% Transparent

<sub>Its implemented in Chrome Canary (v52) .. I'm on linux, couldn't verfiy it.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The hex rgb color code for black should either be `#000` (short form) or `#000000` (full form), but NOT `#0000`

Comment: I already tried changing it to #000000 full form but it is not working on firefox still.

Comment: @user2868864 `color: #000000` works just fine in Firefox 49.0.1: https://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/raf4qtsf/

Comment: yes, same here, as opposed to `#0000`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba

Comment: Thanks everyone. It is working with 000000.